# smoothing between pixels of imagesc\imshow in matlab like the matplotlib imshow

Tags: matlab, matplotlib, plot

When I use matplotlib's `imshow()` in python to represent a small matrix, it produces a some sort if smoothing between pixels. Is there any way to have this in Matlab when using `imshow` or `imagesc`?

For example, using matplotlib this is the output of the identity matrix `imshow(eye(3))`:
[image]

while in matlab,  `imagesc(eye(3))`:

[image]

A solution I can think of is to extrapolate and smooth using some filter, but that won't be relevant for the single pixel levels. I've also tried [myaa](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979-myaa-my-anti-alias-for-matlab) and [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-exportfig), but they are not satisfactory. Myaa is taking all GUI usabily after being applied, so I can't zoom in or out, and export_fig makes me save the figure to a file and then operate on that file, too cumbersome. So, is there a way to tell the figure engine of matlab (java or what not) to do this smoothing while keeping the nice usability of the figure GUI?

Comment: Add interpolation='none' to your imshow command

Answer (score 46):

It is due to the default interpolation which is set to 'bilinear'. I think 'none' would be a more intuitive default. You can change the default interpolation method (eg interpolation=None) with:

```
mpl.rcParams['image.interpolation'] = 'none'
```

More information about customising Matplotlib can be found on the [website](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

The code below will give you an overview of all interpolation methods:

```
methods = [None, 'none', 'nearest', 'bilinear', 'bicubic', 'spline16', 'spline36', 'hanning', 'hamming', \
           'hermite', 'kaiser', 'quadric', 'catrom', 'gaussian', 'bessel', 'mitchell', 'sinc', 'lanczos']

grid = np.random.rand(4,4)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,6,figsize=(12,6), subplot_kw={'xticks': [], 'yticks': []})
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3, wspace=0.05)

ax = ax.ravel()

for n, interp in enumerate(methods):
    ax[n].imshow(grid, interpolation=interp)
    ax[n].set_title(interp)
```

[image]

Comment: otherwise this is a very nice answer.

Comment: Your right, i have refined my initial answer, thanks for pointing that out. The default rcParam could still be set to 'none' though. I think most graphics sotware assume (including Matlab apparently) nearest neighbor as the default, making Lama's surprise understandable.

Comment: excuse me, but I isn't @Lama asking about how to do the smoothing in Matlab instead of asking how to remove it from matplotlib?

Comment: I actually did... the answer is very nice and all (+1) but I did want to have the same interpolation effect in matlab (without the need to interpolate that 3x3 matrix for example)

Comment: @Lama, sorry for the confusion, i misunderstood. Interpolating an identity matrix sounds a bit strange to me but in general its a fair question of course. In Matlab there is an imresize functions which allows bilinear interpolation. Like: outgrid = imresize(ingrid,scalefactor,'bilinear'). But you would need to figure out the desired output size which Matplotlib does 'on-the-fly'.

Comment: Would be willing to make PR adding this grid to the matplotlib gallery?  I think this would be a nice addition.

Comment: @tcaswell, no problem. See: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2599
Im a bit of a github noob so hope i did it right. Otherwise feel free to just add my example yourself.

Comment: Thanks :) That looks fine process wise.  I suspect you will get some feed back from the other devs.