# How to 'turn off' blurry effect of imshow() in matplotlib?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I want to make a color plot of probabilities however imshow generates blurry values for points which have zero probability. How can I get rid of this blurry periphery around real grid points?

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=np.asarray([[  0.00000000e+00 , 1.05824446e-01 ,  2.05086136e-04,   0.00000000e+00],
[  1.05824446e-01 ,  3.15012305e-01  , 1.31255127e-01  , 1.05209188e-01],
 [  2.05086136e-04  , 1.31255127e-01 ,  0.00000000e+00 ,  0.00000000e+00],
 [  0.00000000e+00   ,1.05209188e-01  , 0.00000000e+00  , 0.00000000e+00]])
im=plt.imshow(a,extent=[0,4,0,4],origin='lower',alpha=1,aspect='auto')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 80, accepted):

By default (which is changed mpl 2.0), `imshow` interpolates the data (as you would want to do for an image).  All you need to do is tell it to not interpolate:

```
im = plt.imshow(..., interpolation='none')
```

`'nearest'` will also work for what you want.  See [smoothing between pixels of imagesc\imshow in matlab like the matplotlib imshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722540/smoothing-between-pixels-of-imagesc-imshow-in-matlab-like-the-matplotlib-imshow/14728122#14728122) for examples of all of the kinds of interpolation.

[doc](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow)

Comment: Thank you. The correct attribute is interpolation. 
`im = plt.imshow(..., interpolation='none')`

Comment: Note that some backends do not support `none`, while `nearest` seems to be accepted everywhere.

Comment: @tiago what backends don't take 'none'?  That sounds like a bug to me

Comment: @tcaswell: the `macosx` backend doesn't support it. It throws the following warning: `WARNING: The backend (matplotlib.backends.backend_macosx.RendererMac) does not support interpolation='none'. The image will be interpolated with 'nearest' mode. [matplotlib.image]`

Comment: That should not raise a warning as that is the documented behavior: http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow

Comment: and it behaves as expected, just raising a warning?

Comment: Is there a way to make this the default option, so you don't have to type it in every time (besides defining your own function)?

Comment: pretty sure there is an rcparam

Comment: Why is it 'none' rather than None

Comment: @AdamHughes  `'none'` -> no interpretation `None` -> use the default interpolation

Comment: Makes sense, but I always find myself forgetting this and making the same mistake over and over.  Guess I just need in the habit.

Answer (score 3):

You may also use:

```
im = plt.imshow(..., interpolation='nearest')
```

This works especially well for discrete variables.