# How to turn off blurry effect of imshow of matplotlib?

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

When I am showing image by matlotlib imshow() function, it makes image blurry, however, when I am using cv2.imshow(), it keeps the image as sharp as possible without any sort of blurry effect.

I am using the following code:

```
read_image = cv2.imread('img1.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(read_image, cmap = 'gray')
```

By cv2 we can use the following line of code:

```
cv2.imshow("Image displayed by cv2", read_image)
```

Can some one provide some needful assistance?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to 'turn off' blurry effect of imshow() in matplotlib?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20010882/1248974)

Comment: I have seen this link.