# How to switch off interpolation effect of scatter() in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

Is there a way to plot data points without matplotlib performing (subtle) interpolations between the fill and edge color?

While there is a related question on matplotlib's [imshow()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010882/how-to-turn-off-blurry-effect-of-imshow-in-matplotlib), scatter() does not appear to have a dedicated argument for interpolation.

Example.:

[image: original size]
[image: zoom]

Comment: Usually you can use `antialiased=False` to get rid of the antialiasing. `scatter` seems to ignore this, however.

Comment: I opened an [issue about it](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10825).