# Mpld3: blurry image

Tags: matplotlib, mpld3

I created a matplotlib figure (matplotlib on server) and displaying it with mpld3.draw_figure (nodejs on client) only gives blurry images, similar to the ones here:

[How to 'turn off' blurry effect of imshow() in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20010882/how-to-turn-off-blurry-effect-of-imshow-in-matplotlib)

```
        mpld3.draw_figure(`chartBox-${round}`,chart,false,true)
```

Interpolation setting 'nearest', 'none', did not change anything:

```
        plt.imshow(G,interpolation='nearest')
```

I assume its some interpolation problem... maybe also there is a 0.5 shift, so that gridpoints 1 -> 1.5 and are then interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

First switching back to matplotlib 1.5.1 and then

```
mpl.use('Agg')
```

solved it

see here:
[Generating a PNG with matplotlib when DISPLAY is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801882/generating-a-png-with-matplotlib-when-display-is-undefined)